# Spring + thymleaf failed to render HTML form tag

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I can't understand and can't reproduce what happened, no error logs, thymleaf with spring Boot rendered my login form without HTML form tag in production. Redeployed against everything was working. How can I understand what's happened?

Comment: maybe the page was cached or some weird error, no idea...weirdo

Comment: my for is simple form like this
 <form th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${loginModel}" class="form-signin" method="post">

and I have configs

spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.cache=true
spring.resources.cache-period=86400

Comment: if you tried several times and not able to reproduce again, i would just leave it as a weird poltergeist and wouldn't worry about more

Comment: I fixed issue, I'm using  nekohtml and spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
and i found missed closing </form> tag  in some view. After opening that page every view failed render <form></form> tags. (It skipped only that tag) :D

Comment: but then should fail all times not just once...haha

Answer (score 0):

I fixed issue, I'm using `nekohtml` and `spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5` and i found missed closing  tag in some views. After opening that page every view failed render  tags. (It skipped only that tag)